# Generating new Instance of Class fails at Runtime

Tags: java, generics

i've got a Problem with java and generic classes.
Given the following code

```java
public class A {
    public void n() { 
        System.out.println("In A"); 
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void n() {
        System.out.println("In B");
        super.n();
    }
}

public class C {
    public A m_a;
    public <T extends A> C( Class<T> a ) {
        try {
            m_a = a.newInstance();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void print(){ m_a.n(); };
}
```

i try to instantiate an Object of Class C as following

```
C c = new C( B.class );
```

but get the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: testdbvsfile.Main$B
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at testdbvsfile.Main$C.<init>(Main.java:63)
    at testdbvsfile.Main.main(Main.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: testdbvsfile.Main$B.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)<br>
    ... 3 more
```

How can i make it work?
Thanks for help.

btw: I'm using jre1.8.0_65

Comment: Thus the importance of providing an MCVE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using non-static inner classes. This is evident from the stack trace, where `Main$B` is given for the name of your `B` class, which lacks `static` in its declaration.

Constructors of non-static member classes take an implicit parameter with the instance of their enclosing class.

Making your inner classes `static` will fix this problem. You could also fix the problem by moving your `A`, `B`, and `C` classes out of the `Main` class.

Comment: Good spot! I've been staring at this for five minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I didn't think of that :D